# List and filter file using c REGEX expression

Tags: c, regex, file

In the following code, I am trying to filter out using regex ONLY, the file called test.jpg, what am I doing wrong as the code below is not filtering this out?

I know there are simpler ways, but eventually I would like to change the regex to `^(image_)\\d{3,6}_201412\\d{2}_\\d{6}\\.(jpg)`
and also my folder contains 100,000+ files, so I can only use the c getdents function which is super fast compared to any other way

I get the following output:

> **************found*******
>
> image_0179_20141212_060714.jpg

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
       do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
    long           d_ino;
    off_t          d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
};

#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*5

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, nread;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct linux_dirent *d;
    int bpos;
    char d_type;
    regex_t reg;
    regmatch_t pmatch[40];
    #define NAME "image_0179_20141212_060714.jpg"
    const char *pattern = "^(image_)\\d{3,6}_201412\\d{2}_\\d{6}\\.(jpg)";
    regcomp(&reg, pattern, REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED);
    int retval = 0;
    char buffer[1024] = "";
    fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1)
         handle_error("open");
    for ( ; ; )
    {
       nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
       if (nread == -1)
         handle_error("getdents");
       if (nread == 0)
          break;
       for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;)
       {
           d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buf + bpos);
           d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
           if( d->d_ino != 0 && d_type == DT_REG )
           {
                //printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
                if (strstr(d->d_name, NAME) != NULL)
                {
                    printf("**************found*******\n");
                    printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
                };

                retval = regexec(&reg, d->d_name, 2, pmatch, 0);
                //printf("%d\n",retval);
                if(retval==0)
                {
                    printf("**************found regex*******\n");
                    printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
                }
            }
            bpos += d->d_reclen;
        }
     }
     regfree(&reg);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `getdents`? The manpage says *"These are not the interfaces you are interested in.  Look at readdir(3)"*

Comment: There's a difference between `=` and `==`...

Comment: voting to close as a typo.

Comment: either = or == dot make a difference

Comment: Well `=` is certainly wrong and never true.

Comment: i changed the code to ==

Comment: @Ossama works for *me* now. And you really want to use `readdir` instead of relying on the getdents never changing!

Comment: changed code, sorry guys, this will looks for the following regex instead ^(image_)\\d{3,6}_201412\\d{2}_\\d{6}\\.(jpg)

Comment: how do you propose i change ^(image_)\\d{3,6}_201412\\d{2}_\\d{6}\\.(jpg)

Comment: how do you propose i change ^(image_)\\d{3,6}_201412\\d{2}_\\d{6}\\.(jpg)

Answer (score 1):

use the following regex instead

```
^image_[0-9]{3,6}_201412[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{6}\.jpg$
```